# Implementing comments on feed post in swift using firebase

Tags: arrays, swift, firebase, object, firebase-realtime-database

I am trying to implement a comment section on each feed post in my app using swift and firebase, but am having trouble with the code that will get the comments. In my function it is returning a empty array of `messageComments` but I do not know what I am doing wrong. If I want my firebase database structure to look like that in the picture how can I implement the code that will download those comments in an array?

```
func getFeedMessages(handler: @escaping (_ feedMessages:[FeedMessages]) -> ()){
        var feedMessagesArray = [FeedMessages]()
        var commentArray = [messageComments]()
        REF_FEEDMESSAGES.observeSingleEvent(of: .value) { (feedMessagesSnapshot) in
            guard let feedMessagesSnapshot = feedMessagesSnapshot.children.allObjects as? [DataSnapshot] else {return}

            for messages in feedMessagesSnapshot {
                let content = messages.childSnapshot(forPath: "content").value as? String ?? "Joe Flacco is an elite QB"
                let icon = messages.childSnapshot(forPath: "icon").value as? String ?? "none"
                let color = messages.childSnapshot(forPath: "color").value as? String ?? "bop"


                self.REF_FEEDCOMMENTS.observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { (feedCommentsSnapshot) in
                    guard let feedCommentsSnapshot = feedCommentsSnapshot.children.allObjects as? [DataSnapshot] else {return}

                    for comments in feedCommentsSnapshot {
                        commentArray.append((comments.childSnapshot(forPath: "comments").value as? messageComments!)!)
                    }
                })



                print("             comment:        ")
                print(commentArray)
                let messages = FeedMessages(content: content, color: color, icon: icon, comments: commentArray)
                feedMessagesArray.append(messages)
            }
            handler(feedMessagesArray)
        }
    }
```

[image: Desired firebase database structure]

Answer (score 2):

If you also have the same data structure, there would be no need for another request for the comments since they are nested in the feed messages. This will only require some simple parsing, which can be made easier to read and understand with a few extensions.

```
extension DataSnapshot {
    var string: String? {
        return value as? String
    }
    var childSnapshots: [DataSnapshot] {
        return children.allObjects as? [DataSnapshot] ?? []
    }
    func child(_ path: String) -> DataSnapshot {
        return childSnapshot(forPath: path)
    }
}
```

These two extensions take care of the snapshot operations needed to initialize the objects.

```
extension MessageComments {
    convenience init(snapshot: DataSnapshot) {
        self.comments = snapshot.childSnapshots.map { $0.string }
    }
}

extension FeedMessages {
    convenience init(snapshot: DataSnapshot) {
        self.color = snapshot.child("color").string ?? "bop",
        self.comments = MessageComments(snapshot: snapshot.child("comments"))
        self.content = snapshot.child("content").string ?? "Joe Flacco is an elite QB",
        self.icon = snapshot.child("icon").string ?? "none",
    }
}
```

Just map the children snapshots to initialize each of them as a `FeedMessages` object.

```
func getFeedMessages(handler: @escaping (_ feedMessages: [FeedMessages]) -> ()) {
    REF_FEEDMESSAGES.observeSingleEvent(of: .value) {
        handler($0.childSnapshots.map { FeedMessages(snapshot: $0) })
    }
}
```